# Starvation Condition in CPU/Process Scheduling?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

Let's say OS is using preemptive CPU scheduling. A process P1 gets a chance to run for some time and then next higher priority process comes and preempts P1. After that higher priority processes are coming regularly and P1 never gets chance. Is this condition called starvation or not?

Comment: What do you think? Do you know what starvation means in this context? Do the conditions for starvation hold in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in the wikipedia states
"In computer science, starvation is a problem encountered in concurrent computing where a process is perpetually denied necessary resources to proceeds its work."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_%28computer_science%29

so the condition you stated is starvation because P1 is perpetually denied necessary resources to proceeds its work.